# "a different take" (interpretation/viewpoint) versus "a different tack" (approach/alternative/direction)

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, phrase-usage

I found myself writing "a different take" and wondering if I didn't mean "a different tack".  It got me wondering what the difference, if any, is between these two phrases.

Initially, my view was that "a different tack" is the *correct* phrase and "a different take" was just a common mistake caused by the spelling similarity between *tack* and *take*, and people's familiarity with using *take* in phrases such as "What's your take on all of this?".

I [googled this](https://www.google.com/search?q=take%20versus%20tack) and only found results about *tact* versus *tack* – nothing about *take* versus *tack*. There is a dictionary meaning of *take* as a noun which is relevant: ”a particular version of or approach to something”. *Tack* is a reference to "change course by turning a boat's head into and through the wind", although some dictionaries actually have a more relevant definition which I suspect is derived from the use of the sailing meaning as metaphor:  ["a way in which you do something or try to do something"](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/tack). As noted, I could find nothing on my particular question of *take* versus *tack*.

I have come to believe these are two separate, legitimate phrases. While hard to pin down, I would choose *take* where I mean someone's point of view (e.g., "Donald always has a unique take on things") whereas I would use *tack* to mean something more action oriented, such as "Let's try a different tack to solve this problem."

I think there is substantial overlap when the desired meaning is approach, as both words cover this. In those cases, either phrase can work.

Lastly, I will say that when I started I did not understand why people got confused between *take* and *tact* but I now understand this better. I think that many people are making up a shorthand version of *tactic* which, as of yet, does not exist in English.

Comment: It's also very common to hear "a different **tact**".

Comment: similar - both acceptable

Comment: While you do see “a different ‘tact’” this seems like a clear mistake to me, although understandable given the similarity to tactic.

Comment: I am new to this stackexchange. Why did I get downvotes?

Comment: The downvotes are most likely for the same reason as the closevotes: you haven't included your attempts to find an answer (aka "research"). In this case, you should look in a dictionary to see what you can find and include this in your question. (Googling the phrases will be the best way to find dictionaries with relevant definitions.)

Comment: Thank you @Laurel. I did google beforehand and only found results about tack versus tact - nothing about take. There is a dictionary meaning of take as a noun”a particular version of or approach to something”. I could find nothing on my particular question of take versus tack.

Comment: You should link to the source for all the definitions you quote ***and*** state their source visibly (i.e., not requiring the reader to hover over the link).   It’s OK to use abbreviations like “MW”; see [List of common abbreviations and acronyms](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/147/26083).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're the sort of pair that could eventually become conflated, but they're independent.

One's take on a situation: think of a "take" when filming a movie scene. "Scene 15, take 2." A director might call for more takes after requesting changes to elements of the scene or the shooting of it. A different take on a situation is a different way of looking at it.

In sailing, "tacking" is a technique for heading askew to the direction in which one wants to go when that direction is heading into the wind.

Answer (score 0):

"Take" is a relative overview, a snapshot or focal point. It may lack more details and content than a "tack".

"Tack" also refers to tailoring, *"a long stitch used to fasten fabrics together temporarily, prior to permanent sewing."* "Tack" in tailoring is to temporarily 'pull together'.

And since "tact"
was brought up, it means a plan, or strategy, towards a goal, as in  'tactic'.

They all fit, though each can be asking for a different summation; one an overview, one a point of connection, and one a method, or plan.

Comment: I can see the logic of tact as it relates to tactic but as far as I know that is not one of the accepted definitions of tact.

Comment: I was also surprised to see your definition of tack. While it is legitimate I have always thought tack in this context was the meaning related to sailing.

Comment: @PeterVermont Tack: *Transitive verb*;  to join or add in a slight or hasty manner. *Intransitive verb*; b : to modify one's policy or attitude abruptly. Merriam-Webster, In asking for someone's 'tack' it  could apply as either meaning to put together a hasty summation, or, asking for how a plan might alter with additional information. And, I have always understood that way.